# Event need to be fired, while occurring browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`Window.resize()` event was not triggered, while the browser window size has been changed due to occurrence of the vertical scroll bar in browser.

Could you please suggest any `event` that can be triggered in this case?

Comment: May I see your code, or is it a secret?

Comment: post the code , note that you should use `window.resize()` with lowercase w

Answer (score 0):

If you're open for a non JQuery alternative on solving this:

index.html

```
<body onresize="resizeEvent()"></body>
```

javascript file

```
function resizeEvent() {
  alert("Resizing");
}
```

The key here is adding the 'onresize' into the body of your html file.

I hope it helps.